# Can a udp-client join a specific RPL instance ID in contiki-ng?

Tags: contiki, cooja

I am using the rpl-udp example and I want to deploy 2 udp-servers that will have a different RPL Instance ID (using RPL-Lite). I modified the RPL_DEFAULT_INSTANCE macro, and they create 2 RPL instances. However, when I simulate using Cooja, the udp-clients join both RPL instances depending on which DIO packet they receive. Is it possible to specify to udp-client to join only a specified RPL instance?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such feature. Have you tried to modify DIO processing function? (For example, if a udp-client receives a DIO from a non-target instance, simply drops it).